# Parsing json : Test is json key existing

Tags: json, excel, jira, vba

I'm request with API REST a JIRA filter since Excel and I return my result in a json object. 
I'm parsing this object and I Try to show my result (in a msgbox for now) but I have a problem when the json Key doesn't exist !

A extract of my json :

```
{
    "expand":"schema,names",
    "startAt":0,
    "maxResults":500,
    "total":2,
    "issues":[
    {
        "expand":"operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
        "id":"00001",
        "fields":{
            "components":[
            {
                "id":"01",
                "name":"component_1"
                },
            {
                "id":"02",
                "name":"component_02"
                }
            ]
            }
        },
    {
        "expand":"operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
        "id":"00002",
        "fields":{
            "components":[
            ]
            }
        },
    ]
    }
```

As you cans see, in my first issue (id 00001) I have a 2 components key but in my second issus (id 0002) I don't have component key, because this fields is empty in JIRA for this issue.

So, a part of my code to show my result :

```
For Each Item In jsonObject("issues")

    issueId = Item("id")
    compoId1 = Item("fields")("components")(1)("id")
    compoId2 = Item("fields")("components")(2)("id")
    i = i + 1

    'PRINT_OF_MY_RESULT

Next
```

My problem : 
If my issue (00001) has a "component" value, it's OK and I can return my result but ... if my issus (00002) hasn't a result, my code failled to define compoId ... and my code crash.

Did you have a simple solution ? I try somethings with Exists, isEmpty, etc etc ... but nothing concluent for me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your solution some what like this,

```
For Each Item In jsonObject("issues")
    issueId = Item("id")
    For Each componentItem In jsonObject(Item("fields")("components"))
      If componentItem("id")==1 then
         compoId1 = componentItem("id")
      EndIf
      If componentItem("id")==1 then
         compoId2 = componentItem("id")
      EndIf

    Next
    i = i + 1

    'PRINT_OF_MY_RESULT

Next
```

Comment: Hi,  thx for your help 

I tru this but I have still an error on this line ::
        For Each componentItem In jsonObject(Item("fields")("components"))

 ==> error '13' Type mismatch  .. I don't understand why ... i declare componentItem like Item... as Variant

Comment: Ok, just need to remove jsonObject :: For Each componentItem In Item("fields")("components"). Now I will try to use your method reach my goal ! 
I kepp you inform.